# Apache Spark 2.3.0 : Unable start spark-shell on Windows

Tags: apache-spark

While starting spark-shell, I get the following error.

```
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
**18/04/25 07:18:41 WARN StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Failed to connect to master 10.250.54.201:7077**

    org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult:
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRef(RpcEnv.scala:109)
```

Comment: did you set `10.250.54.201:7077` in spark's configuration files or anywhere else?

Comment: What does your `spark-submit` call look like?

Answer (score 0):

Try following the below steps to resolve the issue

Go to `%SPARK_HOME%\bin` folder in a command prompt

Run `spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master` to run the master. This will give you a URL of the form `spark://ip:port`

Run s`park-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://ip:port` to run the worker. Make sure you use the URL you obtained in step 2.

Run `spark-shell --master spark://ip:port` to connect an application to the newly created cluster.